# dropdown alignment twitter bootstrap 3.0

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

How do I left/right align the two dropwdowns? It's not aligned perfectly because of the labels. I want the two textboxes aligned perfectly. Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2byP.png

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Profession:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddTalent" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
        <asp:ListItem>Model</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Photographer</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Designer</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Fashion Stylist</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Hair Stylist</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Make-up Artist</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<br />
<div class="form-inline">
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Gender:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddGender" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
        <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Any</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

I want it to be like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz3wQ.jpg

Comment: You should remove the <br /> tag.

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Comment: @LoveTrivedi yes, I forgot to ask that as well.. What should I replace instead of <br/> DanielCheung Okay, sorry for that :)

Comment: pull-left and pull-right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making your label a control label should align your elements properly.

Comment: didn't fixed, nothing happened :(

Comment: Did this end up fixing your issue then?

Comment: yup, sorry for the late reply.. I don't have any choice rather than change the width of my labels uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Style Attribute (increment or decrement pixel size to adjust)

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddGender" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" style="margin-left:3px">
```

Comment: same result.. nothing happened :(

Comment: then use like style="margin-left:3px !important"